# thrown-with-msg? throws RuntimeException with Unsupported character

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I am trying to run a test that is expected to throw some exception.
`throws?` works fine but when I try to `thrown-with-msg?` it throws an exception. To test it I picked up lines from [documentation](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html)

Code:

```
(deftest check-exception
  (testing "If Exception is thrown"
    (is (thrown-with-msg? java.lang.ArithmeticException #\"Divide by zero\" (/ 1 0)))))
```

Compilation Error:

> Exception in thread "main" clojure.lang.LispReader$ReaderException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported character: \"Divide

The 3rd parameter that needs to be passed is a `Regular Expression` . How do I pass that?

Comment: Why the `\\` before the quotes? the regexp literal is `#""` - if you want `"` inside use `#"\"...\""`

Comment: i just picked it up from the documentation and pasted it. But i guess it was faulty. I got it working by passing `#"^.*Divide by zero.*$"`

Comment: What docs?  Maybe a PR is in order

Comment: https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html :D

Comment: But you looked at the source instead of that link above? e.g. https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/8e2b1398d1720197a2e3970bd511450a4f2a0ab4/src/clj/clojure/test.clj#L58

Comment: aah.. now i get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal for a regexp in Clojure is `#"... "`.  So the `\` you are using there is wrong.  If you want to have quotes inside the regexp literal, then you quote them like you did.  E.g. `#"\"Divide by zero\""`

**edit**: The source of confusion (literally)

The [source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/8e2b1398d1720197a2e3970bd511450a4f2a0ab4/src/clj/clojure/test.clj#L58) actually contains this line in the doc string:

> ```
> (is (thrown-with-msg? ArithmeticException #\"Divide by zero\"
>                       (/ 1 0)))
> ```

But this is due to the need to quote the `"` within the doc comment as well.  Looking just at the doc with e.g. `doc` in the REPL

```
user=> (require 'clojure.test)
user=> (doc clojure.test)
...
   (is (thrown-with-msg? ArithmeticException #"Divide by zero"
                         (/ 1 0)))
...
```

shows the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is passed as follows:

```
(deftest check-exception
  (testing "If Exception is thrown"
    (is (thrown-with-msg? java.lang.ArithmeticException #"^.*Divide by zero.*$" (/ 1 0)))))
```